# SignalR 2.0.0 beta2 IJsonSerializer extensibility

Tags: json, serialization, signalr

I want to add some custom serialization logic so that the converted json contains camel case properties.

For that reason i tried to replace the default IJsonSerializer with one the i found in this link:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/500

However there seems to be a problem. More specifically, the `JsonNetSerializer` and `IJsonSerializer` classes do not exist in any of the signalR assemblies. Is there any change that happened to the recent version of signalR  in that respect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SignalR 2.0 you can't replace the JsonSerializer, there's no more IJsonSerializer abstraction. It's always JSON.NET.

Comment: How can you override the Contract resolver then? We need our json in camel case.

Comment: @davidfowl how can you add a Converter to the JSON.net formatter that signalr uses? specifiying `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` does not work

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify this a bit, as of SignalR 2 you can't replace the serializer with one that isn't from from JSON.NET. However, the JSON.NET serializer used by SinglR can be created and set using the DependacyResolver.

Here's an example where a new JsonSerializer is created to handle reference loops:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
     var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
     serializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
     serializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

     var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
     GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer); 
  }
```

Comment: Great information! But at the same time bad architecture in signalr... But upvote since I do not shoot the messenger :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The information on https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility is now out of date it seems.

Comment: Indeed. It seems http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection is a much more current reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of overriding the SignalR Dependency Resolver using StructureMap. 
In this particular example, I'm converting to camelCase properties and converting enums as strings.

During startup:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver();
```

Here's the class:

```
public class StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object service;
        if (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass)
        {
            // Concrete type resolution
            service = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            // Other type resolution with base fallback
            service = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
        }

        return service;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var objects = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        return objects.Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
    }
}
```

And StructureMap was setup with:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(c =>
    {
        c.Scan(a =>
            {
                // scan the assembly that SignalR is referenced by
                a.AssemblyContainingType<AppHost>(); 
                a.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

        c.For<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer>()
         .Singleton()
         .Use(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer 
             { 
                 ContractResolver = new SignalRContractResolver(), 
                 Converters = { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter() } 
             });
    });
```

Here is the Contract Resolver:

```
public class SignalRContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;
    private readonly Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver _camelCaseContractResolver;
    private readonly Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver _defaultContractSerializer;

    public SignalRContractResolver()
    {
        _defaultContractSerializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
        _camelCaseContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        _assembly = typeof(Connection).Assembly;
    }

    public Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        if (type.Assembly.Equals(_assembly))
        {
            return _defaultContractSerializer.ResolveContract(type);
        }

        return _camelCaseContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);
    }
}
```