# How to set Json Serializer Settings in SignalR2?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, signalr

I am using Signalr 2, Webapi 2 and Ninject for Ioc and I am in trouble.

In SignalR 2.0 you can't replace the JsonSerializer.
As been answered in here: 
[SignalR 2.0.0 beta2 IJsonSerializer extensibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077200/signalr-2-0-0-beta2-ijsonserializer-extensibility)

I need to ignore ReferenceLoopHandling in json, so I used this code:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings));
```

It all works fine, but I also call signalR clients from Webapi and calling will not work unless I set this code in app start:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(NinjectIocConfig.Kernel);
```

Calling signalR clients from webapi now works but the JSON serialization settings are not used anymore.

How I can get around this or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen my discussion at the end of this issue?

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/500#issuecomment-27480715

The problem is that `kernel.TryGet(serviceType)` will not return null but a default instance since singalR is now usign a concrete type and Ninject will not fail on instancing a unregistered concrete type.

You can check if the concrete type has an explicit binding in the Kernel, if not use the value in the SignalR Dep.resolver

```
kernel.GetBindings(serviceType).Any();
```

Comment: Yes, but I did not understand the suggested solution. Maybe you can show some examples?

Comment: Register it with ninject instead of GlobalHost.DependencyResolver

Comment: Please if you down vote, tell why, if the answer needs improvement we all deserve to know how.

Comment: Did I down vote this? It must been by accident. Your answer is solid and worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Not you but someone else did, not very creative or helpful to downvote without telling whats the problem with the answer, Anyway, I added a alternative solution. You can check if the concrete type is registered with the Kernel