# SignalR JSON Self Referencing Loop Detected

Tags: c#, json, json.net, signalr

I have a .NET class that I am passing from web server to browser client via standard SignalR (C#, ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2013 Community).

This class contains a property that is itself a reference to the same class (i.e. a foreign key reference in database terminology).

```
public class Server
{
    public Guid ServerId;
    public GridLocation Location;
    public DateTime DeployedTs;
    public Server ParentServer;
}
public class GridLocation
{
    public Guid GridLocationId;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public Server ServerAtLocation;
}
```

When my code sends only simple types (int, String as so on) all is ok. As soon as I put in a class with a property that itself refers to my Server class and try to send this to the browser client, I get the error message: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ServerAtLocation' ..."

The code attempting to call the SignalR hub to pass data to connected clients is:

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<WHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.serverStatusChangedToClient(myServer);
```

Where WHub is my Hub which again works fine without these complex classes.

Since this is a SignalR application I am not sure I have any control over the serialization into JSON, or do I? How do I send an instance of this object including the JSON representation of the GridLocation and ParentServer objects (but no further depth in the hierarchy of objects than that)?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Replacing IJsonSerializer serializer here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility, the setting you need is called ReferenceLoopHandling http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm

Though I would strongly advise against passing complex object graphs between application boundaries.

Comment: That's great thanks will check it out. And consider merits of not passing complex object graphs.

Comment: IJsonSerializer no longer exists. Replace it by JsonSerializer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077200/signalr-2-0-0-beta2-ijsonserializer-extensibility

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft.AspNetCore.Signalr(1.1.0) in the startup.cs in ConfigureServices method
You can do the following

```
services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(o =>
            {
                o.PayloadSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

and nowadays (2024, .net8), this should solve it:

```
services.AddSignalR(options => options.EnableDetailedErrors = true).AddJsonProtocol(o =>
{
    var jsonSerializerOptions = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions();
    jsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    o.PayloadSerializerOptions = jsonSerializerOptions;
});
```